# why multiple image is not display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

I am trying to display multiple images in a PDF using jspdf. It only shows the first image. It's not showing another image? Can we show multiple images using jspdf? Here is my code:

PLUNKER: http://plnkr.co/edit/HxharsFKeOPn2JgTb6pu?p=preview

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.setFontSize(40);
doc.text(35, 25, "Paranyan loves jsPDF");
doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 180, 'Octonyan');
doc.addImage('Octonyan', 'JPEG', 15, 400, 180, 180);
doc.save('Test.pdf');
```

Comment: Can you post the full code?  And I think one of the two addImage invocations is wrong.  From the documentation I get, that you should insert a dataUri in the first parameter.  So you second addImage is wrong.

Comment: @EdgarKlerks please check my plunker

Comment: please check updated one http://plnkr.co/edit/HxharsFKeOPn2JgTb6pu

Answer (score 0):

You're adding an image outside of the page of a single-paged document
The following works, mind the changed `y` coordinate `400 -> 220`

```
doc.addImage(imgData1, 'JPEG', 15, 220, 180, 180);
```